# Unable to run Scala-Neo4j project from command line

Tags: java, scala, neo4j, noclassdeffounderror, scala-ide

I developed a Java project in which I wrote some Scala classes and some Java classes. I used [Scala-Neo4j wrapper](https://github.com/FaKod/neo4j-scala) in the project to write Scala functions for inserting and retrieval of Neo4j nodes. I also wrote Thrift services in java in the project as I need to call these Scala functions from Php. Finally I extracted a jar file using Eclipse and I tried to run it from the command line and I got the following Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/scala/Neo4jWrapper
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at dum.Sad.main(Sad.scala)
    at dum.ScalaRunner.main(ScalaRunner.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.scala.Neo4jWrapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 14 more
```

It works completely fine when I run the project from Eclipse. But, while running the jar file which I extracted from the project I get the Exception above. Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your are not setting the classpath up properly. Try this:

```
scala -cp ./where/is/Neo4jWrapper/jar YourClass
```

Of course, replace `./where/is/Neo4jWrapper/jar` with the path to the .jar. Notice that if you need to point to more than one jar or class directory you need to separate them with `:` if on Linux/Mac or `;` if in Windows. And avoid spaces in the classpath.

Comment: I kept all the jars in a folder called lib and added it to the project